# How do you control what is deployed with Maven2 to the Nexus?

Tags: deployment, maven-2, nexus

I can't figure out how to control what artifacts are deployed to our local company Nexus.  We've got a software product that has installation files that are constructed during the package, but then maven doesn't deploy them.  How do I configure which artifacts are stored for people to access?  Am I missing some fundamental point of deploying a release?

Comment: I had edited your question to try to attract it more direct attention as per point 3 in this [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648) regarding leading with the most important words. The "What is"/"How do"/etc can sometimes add unnecessary length to the question, resulting in more people glossing over it amongst the many other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to use the build-helper-maven-plugin.
Be careful with the classifiers and types, because the thing renames your files assuming it knows what you want.  I hope to write code that allows me to punch maven in its bits through the screen.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
       <execution>
          <id>install-installation</id>
          <phase>install</phase>
          <goals>
             <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
             <artifacts>
                <artifact>
                   <file>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-Setup.exe</file>
                   <classifier>Setup</classifier>
                   <type>exe</type>
                </artifact>
                <artifact>
                   <file>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-Linux-x86-Install</file>
                   <classifier>Linux-x86</classifier>
                   <type>Install</type>
                </artifact>
                <artifact>
                   <file>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-Linux-x86_64-Install</file>
                   <classifier>Linux-x86_64</classifier>
                   <type>Install</type>
                </artifact>
                <artifact>
                   <file>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip</file>
                   <type>zip</type>
                </artifact>
             </artifacts>
          </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```